# Как обновить viewpager или listfragment?

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в следующем вопросе. У меня есть ViewPager с FragmentPagerAdapter и десять ListFragment которые заполняются с базы данных, проблема заключается в следующем, когда я удаляю элемент с ListFragment он сразу не исчезает, а надо пролистать на пару страниц в сторону и вернуться чтоб данные обновились. Как сделать чтоб ListFragment обновлялся сразу после удаления элемента?
Туплю уже второй день, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У FragmentPagerAdapter перегрузите метод вот таким образом

```
        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(final Object object)
        {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
```

И когда удаляете элемент, вызывайте

```
yourFagmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```